# Convert an ASP.net Singleton Session Instance to an object

Tags: session, singleton, instance

So I've taken over a VB.net web application project from another developer and have discovered a glaring issue with the code written to date.

The developer has built a shopping cart application based on this tutorial (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/build-a-shopping-cart-in-aspnet/).

NOTE: To any developer considering using this as the basis for a production ASP.net shopping cart - DON'T - read on to find out more....

The person who wrote that tutorial realized too late that using a Singleton was not a very clever pattern for a session based Shopping Cart. In fact it's dumb - really dumb. With this pattern every user has the same shopping cart instance!

There are numerous helpful comments in the tutorial about how to convert the Singleton instance session into an object (like this one from the author: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/build-a-shopping-cart-in-aspnet/comment-page-1/#comment-56782).

But my application uses the VB.net equivalent (available in the download files on that page) and what I'm wondering is will I need to go through the entire application and remove all references to the likes of:

```
ShoppingCart.Instance.AddItem
```

And manually replace them with something like:

```
Dim cart As ShoppingCart = ShoppingCart.GetShoppingCart()
```

cart.AddItem(3)

Or is there something smarter I can do to convert this code:

```
#Region "Singleton Implementation"

' Readonly variables can only be set in initialization or in a constructor
Public Shared ReadOnly Instance As ShoppingCart
' The static constructor is called as soon as the class is loaded into memory
Shared Sub New()
    ' If the cart is not in the session, create one and put it there
    ' Otherwise, get it from the session
    If HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart") Is Nothing Then
        Instance = New ShoppingCart()
        Instance.Items = New List(Of CartItem)
        HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart") = Instance
    Else
        Instance = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart"), ShoppingCart)
    End If
```

Into something else so I don't need to change the instance calls?

e.g. something like this (this is a C# code snippet I found in another comment in the article - I'd need a VB.net equivalent but I'm not sure how to write it - my VB.net is a bit rusty!)

```
public static ShoppingCart Instance
{
    get
    {
        ShoppingCart c=null;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] == null)
        {
            c = new ShoppingCart();
            c.Items = new List();
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(“ASPNETShoppingCart”, c);
        }
        else
        {
            c = (ShoppingCart)HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"];
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Ed

Comment: What are the storage options?  Is it all in memory or is it backed by SQL etc...?

Comment: @bryanmac fair enough :) I don't intentionally not accept answers.

Comment: @bryanmac - I'm stuck with Inproc (memory) - I have a CMS that only supports Inproc (it can't serialize session data apparently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You don't need to change the instance calls if you do the code above.  In most instance calls, they create the static object if null and stuff it away in the static member variable and continue to hand the same one out (with some double lock checks perhaps).  In the code above, you don't do that - you turn around and give out the one in their session state dictionary so each each will get a different one.

The term instance in that case will be a little mis-leading but you don't have to change all the calling code.  It will logically be an instance of their shopping cart.

...

Using the HttpContext.Current.Session dictionary will allow you to store a cart in memory per shopping user.

The downside of an in-memory session is if the IIS application pool recycles, it will be gone.  Also, if you ever have to add another web server (scale out), you'll need to use NLB affinity - it just limits your options.  Your memory also grows since their cart would stay in memory for the lifetime of the session - but that's a good problem for a shopping site :) But, it's dead simple and light weight.

Other options would be to either store session state in a DB via configuration or roll your own shopping cart tables.

Yet another option would be to use cloud storage - something like Azure table services.  That way you get the best of both worlds - you don't have to maintain your SQL server, you get redundancy and durability across recycles etc... And hey - you can play with a new technology at the same time :)

Comment: perfect @bryanmac - see I do accept answers - when they're as good as yours :)

Comment: :) Thx -I usually answer anyways but I poke hoping to help folks.  Some don't realize ..

Answer (score 0):

Using this code

public static ShoppingCart Instance
    {
        get
        {

```
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] == null)
        {

            // we are creating a local variable and thus

            // not interfering with other users sessions

            ShoppingCart instance = new ShoppingCart();

            instance.Items = new List<CartItem>();

            HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] = instance;

            return instance;

        }
        else
        {

            // we are returning the shopping cart for the given user

            return (ShoppingCart)HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"];

        }

    }
}
```